# How to iterate through elements of a list?

Tags: python, json

kind of a new to the python realm so I apologize if this question seems a little too elementary but I can't seem to find an answer to something I am having a problem with.

Ultimately I am building a nested json and within the json is a list.
Example:

```
d = {"Names": [{"FirstName": "John", "LastName": "Smith"}]}
```

Say the first time through I get an update that I want to insert into my list:

```
update = {"FirstName": "Mary", "LastName": "Poppins"}
```

I need to update the list and add a new entry:

```
d["Names"][]=update
```

My question is what is supposed to go in "[]" to get it to add to the next element to the list without specifying a specific number?

I want it to look kind of like this:

```
d = {"Names": [{"FirstName": "John", "LastName": "Smith"},{"FirstName": "Mary", "LastName": "Poppins"} ]}
```

I don't know how to do this without explicitly stating the numbers (which I already know how to do).  Am I going about this the wrong way?

Comment: `d["Names"].append(update)`

Comment: Note this is a *list*, not an *array* (Python doesn't have arrays as a core data structure).

Comment: @Lattyware I removed mentions of `array`. It's a common mistake.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As [Daniel](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3555845/daniel) posted in the comments:

```
d = {"Names": [{"FirstName": "John", "LastName": "Smith"}]}
```

This is dictionary `{}` containing one key, `"Names"`. The value of `"Names"` is a list containing one dictionary.

```
keys       values
"Names"    [{"FirstName": "John", "LastName":"Smith"}]
```

If you want to add an element to the list contained in `d["Names"]`, just treat it like a list!

```
update = {"FirstName": "Mary", "LastName": "Poppins"}
d["Names"].append(update)
```

Now it looks like this:

```
keys       values
"Names"    [{"FirstName": "John", "LastName":"Smith"},
            {"FirstName": "Mary", "LastName":"Poppins"}]
```

So you can do:

```
for name in d["Names"]:
    # d["Names"] is the [{...}, {...}]
    # name is each element, so just each dictionary in turn
    print(name["FirstName"], name["LastName"])
```

Comment: Thank you so much, this actually helped me!  The confusion for me was that json considers [] to be an array and I didn't know that python would just see it as a list; thought I had to do something entirely different.  Thank you for clarifying!

Comment: @user3614014 lists are arrays (kinda but not really)